# What BNF Variant is This?

Tags: bison, bnf

I was looking into making a Bison-based parser using some BNF files I found on Github. My issue, however, is that I cannot seem to determine what variation of BNF the files are using.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/dyoo/ragg/tree/master/ragg/examples/) to a folder containing samples of the BNF variant.

In [bnf.rkt](https://github.com/dyoo/ragg/blob/master/ragg/examples/bnf.rkt), the author references the [BNF Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), yet his file looks nothing like it:

```
## The following comes from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form
<syntax> : <rule> | <rule> <syntax>
<rule> : <opt-whitespace> "<" <RULE-NAME> ">" <opt-whitespace> "::="
<opt-whitespace> <expression> <line-end>
<opt-whitespace> : " " <opt-whitespace> | "" ## "" is empty string, i.e. no whitespace
<expression> : <list> | <list> "|" <expression>
<line-end> : <opt-whitespace> <EOL> | <line-end> <line-end>
<list> : <term> | <term> <opt-whitespace> <list>
<term> : <literal> | "<" <RULE-NAME> ">"
<literal> : '"' <TEXT> '"' | "'" <TEXT> "'" ## actually, the original BNF did not use quotes
```

Here is an example ([from the repo](https://github.com/dyoo/ragg/blob/master/ragg/examples/baby-json.rkt)) of how this syntax is used to represent basic JSON:

```
;; Simple baby example of JSON structure
json: number | string
| array
| object
number: NUMBER
string: STRING
array: "[" [json ("," json)*] "]"
object: "{" [kvpair ("," kvpair)*] "}"
kvpair: ID ":" json
```

Does anyone have any idea of what he is using? I would like to convert this into a Bison-readable format, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kind of extended BNF, similar to that used in various parser generators, roughly based on bison syntax with the addition of brackets and regular expression operators. The documentation is [here](https://www.hashcollision.org/ragg/#%28part._ragg-syntax%29), and a summary would be:

- The left-hand-side of a production is followed by <kbd>:</kbd>, as in bison.
- There is no <kbd>;</kbd> at the end of a production (in bison, the <kbd>;</kbd> is optional).
- <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> are the usual Kleene star and plus operators found in most regex libraries. <kbd>|</kbd> is the usual alternation operator. <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> are grouping parenthesis, also similar to most regex implementations.
- However, optional sequences are surrounded with <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>, similar to EBNF.

Aside from the last point, that makes it essentially the same as the basic format used by ANTLR, for example.